How can I avoid my ERC-721 token to be added to hidden/suspicious NFTs by Metamask?
I have deployed an ERC-721 collection and mint a new NFT token with proper metadata URL.
The NFT displays perfectly on OpenSea, so ERC-721 code and the JSON  Metadata should be fine:
https://opensea.io/assets/matic/0xBE687297a155e729e9cf541D14a4Fd7895799B1c/5
The problem is that it is considered spam/malicious by Metamask and most wallets.
This is my process:
1- I'm creating an NFT collection, with Solidity, based on the ERC-721 standard, just following OpenZeppelin guidelines. The contract is verified in PolygonScan.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.26;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";

contract Collection is ERC721URIStorage {
    uint256 public _nextTokenId;

    constructor() ERC721("Coleccion Interesante", "CINT") {}

    function mintItem(string memory uri)
        public
        returns (uint256)
    {
        uint256 tokenId = _nextTokenId++;
        _mint(msg.sender, tokenId);
        _setTokenURI(tokenId, uri);
        return tokenId;
    }
}

2- When I mint a new NFT Token, the value provided to tokenURI is a valid URL responding with a JSON following the Opensea Metadata Standard, you can check it here:
The  URL like this I'm using returns a well formatted JSON, compliance with the Standard:
{
  "description": "Description de ejemplo para que sepamos lo que pasa.", 
  "external_url": "https://videomuse.co", 
  "image": "https://t3.ftcdn.net/jpg/04/19/17/68/360_F_419176802_9s4AoYMfzxDt3kaSYV55whCkTB76NsHN.jpg", 
  "name": "Pablo Montoya",
  "attributes": [{
      "trait_type": "Color", 
      "value": "Rojo"
    }, 
    {
      "trait_type": "Size", 
      "value": "Small"
    }, 
    {
      "trait_type": "Cara", 
      "value": "Sorpresa"
    }]
}

Main problem: Hidden NFT in Metamask Portfolio
The problem is that for some reason, when I check NFT tab in Metamask Portolio the NFT does not appear, and I need to look for it in the "hidden NFTs" section, where it is located by default with the rest of SPAM tokens.
Problem in wallets

In Metamask (browser extension) I cannot see the image preview when I add the NFT (address + ID). However, I can see the preview in Metamask's mobile app.
In Phantom wallet, the NFT appears hidden and with a warning icon.
In Truswallet I cannot add or search for the NFT, in any way.

How can I fix it? What are the reason to be classified as spam???
